# Views footer include twig

Tags: views, 8, theming

Is there any way to include an if condition in views footer. I have to check the total rows

```
{% if [view:total-rows]  > 6 %}
<div class="btn">View AllEvents</div>
{% endif %}
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your template file? Depending on what template you use,

```
{% if view.total_rows > 6 %}
  <div ...
{% endif %}
```

should work.

Comment: If you talk about views.view.html.twig, just use "rows" instead of "view.total_rows".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this [page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/twig-tweak-and-views).

Install the [twig tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module. And use the link described above.